# How to get the slug of current user?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I am working on a problem where I need to get the slug of current user for updating their information.In model I have stored the username in slug but I cannot access slug in template.

I have tried using request.user to get the username in slug but it displays page not found error.

models.py

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Roles)
    verified =models.BooleanField(default = False,blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, default='default/testimonial2.jpg')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=False, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
         super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username
```

template

```
 <a class="nav-link " href="{% url 'NewApp:userupdate' slug=request.user %}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{request.user.username}} </a>
```

url

```
  url(r'^userupdate/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$',views.UserUpdateView.as_view(),name='userupdate'),
```

Comment: Please, share the `views.py` which renders this template.

Answer (score 3):

Access the slug field using dot notation and create url as given below.

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'NewApp:userupdate' request.user.slug %}" >
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ request.user }} 
</a>
```

I hope this will help you :)